# Draggable is not working inside modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I trying to implement swapping of div using `dragging` and `dropping`. 
It is working fine without modal popup.

But the dragging and dropping is not working  when I implement the same inside the modal popup.

What am I missing ?

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <div class='droppable'>
    <div class="draggable">Draggable 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class='droppable'>
    <div class="draggable">Draggable 2</div>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

**javaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      window.startPos = window.endPos = {};

      makeDraggable();

      $('.droppable').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'hoverClass',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          var $from = $(ui.draggable),
              $fromParent = $from.parent(),
              $to = $(this).children(),
              $toParent = $(this);

          window.endPos = $to.offset();

          swap($from, $from.offset(), window.endPos, 200);
          swap($to, window.endPos, window.startPos, 1000, function() {
            $toParent.html($from.css({position: 'relative', left: '', top: '', 'z-index': ''}));
            $fromParent.html($to.css({position: 'relative', left: '', top: '', 'z-index': ''}));
            makeDraggable();
          });
        }
      });

      function makeDraggable() {
        $('.draggable').draggable({
          zIndex: 99999,
          revert: 'invalid',
          start: function(event, ui) {
            window.startPos = $(this).offset();
          }
        });
      }

      function swap($el, fromPos, toPos, duration, callback) {
        $el.css('position', 'absolute')
          .css(fromPos)
          .animate(toPos, duration, function() {
            if (callback) callback();
          });
      }
    });
```

[**Draggable Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BKUM/cr5w9okh/)

[**Draggable Demo inside modal popup**](https://jsfiddle.net/BKUM/DTcHh/16822/)

Comment: First of all, do not forget to add jquery and jquery ui in your fiddle :D

Comment: Already added in external resources if you have observed :-P

Comment: everything is working but you got some dimensions problem fix it to the dragging look better @BKM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because the modal by default is `display: none;` so the the javascript can't find the elements to init the function for dragging!

what you need to do is to delay the drag function until the elements are not displayed to none.

other than that the dragging is working, the fiddle was messed up because it was missing the jQuery file, also don't forget the priorities jQuery must be the first JS file to be loaded

https://jsfiddle.net/2eysmghe/2/

Comment: But when we are swapping the divs are moving to the bottom while animating